# Degradado color css html

Tags: html, css

Quiero formar una especie de barra de progreso que va degradando el color principal.

Empezando desde el rojo, hasta un rojo muy claro y finalmente el blanco.

una cosa así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imaginad que el amarillo es un rojo clarito (no se hacerlo con paint.)

El caso que tengo en mi html:

```css
.rojo{
  width:600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:#F54021;
  background:linear-gradient(left, #F54021, 60%, #D95030, 30%, white , 10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="rojo">
</div>
```

El problema al ejecutar que toda la barra es de color rojo, no hace ningún degradado y también me he dado cuenta que sólo coge esta línea

```
background-color:#F54021;
```

Si pongo negro o azul o lo que sea va a ser el color final de la barra...

**Edito**:
 El degradado va desde la parte de la izquierda a la derecha.

Gracias

Comment: No conozco mucho el degradado, pero hace poco tuve que realizar [este](https://jsfiddle.net/cvmd7huz/) espero que te sea de ayuda

Comment: El problema es que eso va desde el centro.

Comment: He editado el fiddle a ver si es lo que quieres

Comment: Estoy cambiando el circle at center por left, porque quiero que empiece por la izquierda y deja de funcionar DX

Comment: Existen "gradient generators" que de manera visual puedes crear el gradiente que quieres y te devuelve el código css. Ejemplo: [Gradient editor](https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto es un [ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) del degradado, aplícalo a tu proyecto

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#grad1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FF0000, #FF3633, #FE615E);     }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="grad1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

;

Comment: Funciona lo tuyo, pero si pongo to right, #FF0000 , 60%, #FF3633, 30%, #FE615E, 10%); Para que apartir del 60% empiece a degradarse y el último tramo del 10% sea blanco, no funciona.

Comment: Parece que solo poniendo un "%" si funciona (por ejemplo `background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FF0000,60% #FF3633, #FE615E);`, prueba jugando con eso, si no te vale, buscamos otra solución

Comment: bueno gracias, ya me las apaño con esto :)

Answer (score 6):

Como te he puesto en el comentario hoy en día es fácil encontrar alguna herramienta/web con la que podemos crear de manera visual (en este caso un degradado para luego obtener el `CSS`, se pueden encontrar por "[css gradient generator](https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/])". (También existen otros muy comunes que son para las sombras "css shadow generator").

El generador te devolverá varios css para que sea compatible con distintos navegadores.

---

### linear-gradient

Esta respuesta esta basada en la funcion `CSS` **[linear-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)** y tambien puedes  [ver compatibilidad con navegadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Browser_compatibility)

> `linear-gradient([<angle> | to <side-or-corner> ,]? <color-stop>[[<stop-position]] [,<color-stop>[<stop-position]])`

Para tu ejemplo el código mas simple sería:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, red, white);
```

Las `color-stop` o paradas de color son opcionales por lo que podemos tener 2 (menos no tiene sentido en un degradado) o `n`. Del mismo modo las `stop-position` o posicion de la parada también son opcionales. La primera y la última parada toman como valores por defecto `0%` y `100%`, y el resto toman como valor por defecto la mitad entre la anterior parada y la siguiente `(parada|parada|parada)==(0%|50%|100%)`

Que es lo mismo que:

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 0%, white 100%);
```

```css
.rojo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, white);
}
```

```html
<div class="rojo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Los argumentos de `linear-gradient` están mal, por lo que el navegador ignorará toda la línea `background-image`. Si estuviera bien, la definición `background-color` sería innecesaria.

El modo correcto es:

```css
.rojo {
  width:600px;
  height: 200px;
  /* background-color:#F54021; */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #F54021, #D95030 60%, white 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="rojo"></div>
```

En `linea-gradient`, primero va la dirección (`to right`). Luego el color de inicio (`#F54021`), seguido de los *color stoppers*. `#D95030 60%` indica que el degradado se hace `#D95030` al llegar al 60% del recorrido. Observa que se separa con un espacio, no con comas.